# Published version of AngularJS application does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-injector, cassette

I have AngularJS application in Visual Studio 2015, previous versions work well in production. The last version also works well in debug mode, also published on my local machine. The problem gets tricky when the above mentioned published version is set to webserver. The application does not load at all. The errors in console looks like this[image]

Also, the application uses http://getcassette.net/ for bundling. Also, the app.js file is where controllers and services are stored. I reviewed my code multiple times, also checked the logs in SVN. The changes are minimal. There is no return statement outside a function call, to get the first error, i.e. Illegal return statement.

Comment: UPDATE: works only when there is <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" /> in WEB.config. But that is not a solution.

Comment: UPDATE: The problem lies in Map object in javascript. When I comment the parts where it is initialized and used, the application works as it's expected. Probably Map object is more time consuming, and in debug mode, it has enough time to finish.